# Refresh JavaScript section only?

Tags: javascript

I have a section of JavaScript that displays the current temperature, but it does not update as the temperature changes. Is there a way to have that section of JavaScript update on a timer?

EDIT: Sorry, here's the code (not created by me).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// javascript will go here
$(function(){

// Specify the ZIP/location code and units (f or c)
var loc = '10001'; // or e.g. SPXX0050
var u = 'f';

var query = "SELECT item.condition FROM weather.forecast WHERE location='" + loc + "' AND u='" + u + "'";
var cacheBuster = Math.floor((new Date().getTime()) / 1200 / 1000);
var url = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent(query) + '&format=json&_nocache=' + cacheBuster;

window['wxCallback'] = function(data) {
    var info = data.query.results.channel.item.condition;
    $('#wxIcon').css({
        backgroundPosition: '-' + (61 * info.code) + 'px 0'
    }).attr({
        title: info.text
    });
    $('#wxIcon2').append('<img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/' + info.code + '.gif" width="40" height="40" title="' + info.text + '" />');
    $('#wxTemp').html(info.temp + '&deg;' + (u.toUpperCase()));
};

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    cache: true,
    jsonpCallback: 'wxCallback'
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: AJAX call to God? Seriously, we need more information...

Comment: Show a fiddle so we can help

Comment: How do you measure the current temperature? JS does not have a built-in function for that.

Comment: Since when has "show a fiddle" become a substitute for "show some code"?

Comment: @FelixKling - Rumor has it this will be added in ECMA 7!

Comment: @adeneo: So in... what... like 20 years? I'm probably too optimistic though.

Comment: @FelixKling - I think the temperature function will be added when computers fits up our a55, at least then it does something useful !

Comment: Gee, there's code. Do a setInterval to regularly poll YahooApis to check for changes in the returned data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

name your function (instead of using `$(function(){...`) something like GetWeather

and then somewhere outside ...

```
setInterval(GetWeather,10000)
```

TRY IT : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bvyDh

Comment: btw, not sure if you want to use "append" for the icon, maybe "html" instead :)

Comment: btw something else to consider is the frequency the data is updated. http://help.yahoo.com/l/uk/yahoo/weather/weather-06.html no sense in pinging it 6 times a minute if its updated once an hour